# A way to refer to this current 'votable' element in an action in Rails (e.g. either @post and @comment)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models, **Post** and **Comment** that have a polymorphic association with another model called **Vote**.

**post.rb** and **comment.rb** have `has_many :votes, :as => :votable, :dependent => :destroy`
**vote.rb** has `belongs_to :votable, :polymorphic => true`

This controller has two actions one to add up votes for **Post** and the other for **Comment**:

**controllers/votes_controller.rb:**

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def vote_up
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.votes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id)
      @notice = 'You already voted'
    else
      @vote = @post.votes.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :polarity => 1)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def vote_up2
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

    if @comment.votes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id)
      @notice2 = 'You already voted'
    else
      @vote2 = @comment.votes.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :polarity => 1)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I think that's unnecesary. Is there any way of using a single name to refer to the current votable element or either **@post** and **@comment**?

**Edit**

**routes.rb:**

```
 get 'votes/:id/vote_up' => 'votes#vote_up', as: 'vote_up'
 get 'votes/:id/vote_down' => 'votes#vote_down', as: 'vote_down'
```

Comment: You can also pass to route additional parameter, for example, `:model_name` like `get 'votes/:model_name/:id/vote_up'`. And then when you call `link_to` just pass `:model_name => your_object.class.to_s.downcase` and you'll have like `votes/post/1/vote_up`. Then in controller you can get `:model_name` with `params[:model_name]` and do `@object = params[:model_name].capitalize.constantize.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 1):

The `vote_up` action should be implemented in your `posts` and `comments` controller respectively. Users are voting on posts or comments, they're not voting on a vote.

I would extract the voting logic and place it in a module that your models will include, then call it *on* a votable object from the controller.

in your `lib` directory, create `votable.rb`

```
module Votable
  def up_vote_from(usr)
    place_vote(1, usr.id)
  end

  def down_vote_from(usr)
    place_vote(-1, usr.id)
  end

  private

  def place_vote(direction, usr_id)
    v = self.votes.find_or_create_by_user_id(usr_id)
    v.update_attribute(:polarity, direction)
  end
end
```

(This revised code will alter a user's original vote if they vote again. Vote methods will return `true` if the vote saves, `false` otherwise.)

In each votable model, such as `post.rb` and `comment.rb`, add this line to mix in your voting methods:

```
include Votable
```

Now, this can be done in a controller:

```
@post.up_vote_from current_user # => true
```

As far as implementation is concerned, you will end up with some repetition in your controllers/routes.

In each votable controller, set something up like:

```
def cast_vote
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  if @post.call("#{params[:updown]}_vote_from", current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  else
    head :not_found
  end
end
```

(this expects `.../posts/123/vote/up` for an upvote, `.../posts/123/vote/down` for a downvote.)

then append each resource to include your vote method:

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    post 'vote/:updown', :to => "posts#cast_vote", :as => :vote_on
  end
end
```

which can be called in your views with:

```
<%= button_to "Up", :url => vote_on_post_path(@post, "up"), :remote => true %>
<%= button_to "Down", :url => vote_on_post_path(@post, "down"), :remote => true  %>
```

This is a lot less work than it looks. It'll make sense once you put it in place. It'll make even more sense if you code it in by hand vs. cut and paste. :)